# Scatterplots using csv files

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

[I want to create a 3-D scatterplot using only two variables of the csv file, I tried plotting a simple 2-D one and I keep getting a KeyError. How can I fix my problem.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GVihM.png)

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/theet/Desktop/ITMLA/Assignment/merka_agri_corn_experiment.csv")
df[:]

x= df["fertilizer_addition"]
y = df["corn_weight"]
plt.scatter(x,y)
plt.title("30 day experiment: Relation between fertilizer quantity and corn weight.")
plt.xlabel("Fertilizer Amount")
plt.ylabel("Corn Weight")
plt.show()
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please share the [minimal reproducible sample](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). The image added could be formatted as code in your question, find here on [How to format](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). This will make life easier for the community to reproduce the issue and provide a solution. Also, do nor forget to add sample data.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to find the key "fertilizr addition", which looks like a spelling mistake - I'm assuming you meant "fertilizer addition" which is why it's saying the key doesn't exist.

Also, please post your code in your question.

Comment: Thanks, I just figured it out a couple of minutes ago. Although how can I change the scatterplot to 3-D?

Comment: A simple google search: https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/04.12-three-dimensional-plotting.html